# Redefine ? (help) function for certain classes

Tags: r

Is it possible to redefine the `?` function (help function) for an R class?

I tried defining

```
`?.myclass` = function(x) "foo"
help.myclass = function(x) "foo"
```

but it doesn't change the behavior of `?`.

```
f = function() "bar"
class(f) = "myclass"
?f                   # doesn't work
help(f)              # doesn't work
help.myclass(f)      #works
```

I am writing a package that uses `PythonInR` to import some Python functions. I was hoping I could add a class to the imported Python functions that would allow me to create a custom help function that called `help(fun)` in Python and print the results. I can write a `python.help` function that does this but I was hoping for a more seamless solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
library(PythonInR)

`?` <- function(e1, e2) UseMethod("?")
`?.default` <- utils::`?`

`?.pyFunction` <- function(e1, e2) {
    topicExpr <- substitute(e1)
    pyHelp(deparse(topicExpr))
}

pyImport("getcwd", from="os", as="os")

? os.getcwd
```

Furthermore you would need the following in your Namespace file.

```
export("?")
S3method("?", "default")
S3method("?", "pyFunction")
```

But for this function to work it is important that your function has the same name in Python and R.

I believe it would be maybe better you create .Rd files for your R functions.